# How to get the size of a function in bytes in GNU assembler with Intel syntax?

Tags: linux, x86, gnu-assembler

I need to compute the size of a function in bytes at assembly time. I've tried various ways, including:

```
.set chk0_sz, offset chk0_e -  offset chk0_s
```

and then using `mov rcx, offset chk0_sz` to get the value.

However, it gives the error:

`error: cannot use more than one symbol in memory operand`.

Here `chk0_e` and `chk0_s` are two labels denoting the end and start of the function, respectively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You only need the `offset` keyword when using an address as an immediate.  In other contexts, like as data, it can't be dereferenced anyway so the symbol *is* the address.

Compilers typically use stuff like `.size chk0,  . -  chk0`.  So you probably want

```
.equ  chk0_sz, . - chk0     # at the end of chk0
```

`.` is the current position, it replaces using `chk0_e` if you put the `.equ` at that position.

---

And obviously you can't use `rcx` (a register) as part of an assemble-time-constant calculation.  Or did you mean `mov rcx, offset chk0_sz` to *use* the size?

If you define it as an assemble-time constant with `.equ`, you'd just do `mov ecx, chk0_sz`.  MASM-style syntax is inconsistent, so this is a mov-immediate not a load because of how `chk0_sz` was defined.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is `mov rcx, offset chk0_sz`. Is AT&T more consistent wrt. syntax?

Comment: @Shuzheng: I was comparing with NASM, another major flavour of intel-syntax (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info), where `mov ecx, symbol` is always a mov-immediate, whether symbol is a label or an EQU constant.  But AT&T syntax is fairly consistent, too: you *always* need a `$` on an immediate.  Like `mov $1, %eax` or `mov $label, %eax` or `mov $equ_constant, %eax`.