# I cannot use MOVABS in gas assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Having this:

```
.text
str:
    .string "string"
    .globl main
main:
    mov $0, %eax
    mov $str, %rdi #cannot use $str
    call printf
    call exit
```

compiler gives err:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
```

I have read somewhere, the `mov $str, %rdi` translates to `movabsq $str, %rdi`, since the size of first operand `$str`, is address and is greater then 32bits and needs to be passed "full" (absolute value). But that would only work on x32 architecture as told me someone here [Why does not XORing %eax causes segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196157/why-does-not-xoring-eax-causes-segfault?noredirect=1#comment110018021_62196157). So now the only way to use address of that string and pass it to the `printf` is use `lea str(%rip), %rdi`. But that is one more instruction added, instead of use immediate. So why cannot I use immediate?

Comment: That is not the case.  If you don't use `movabs` explicitly, GAS assumes you want to use a 32-bit sign-extended immediate (`movq`), which would make sense for an address if linking into a non-PIE executable.  Also, `lea` is an *alternative* to `movabs $str, %rdi`, not an extra instruction.

Comment: If you had an *assemble-time* constant like `0x123456789abc`, then the size of the number would be visible to the *assembler* (not just at link time), and it would pick `movabs` to be able to encode the immediate operand.  **Addresses are link-time constants, not assemble-time.**

Comment: Then why GAS *assume* 32-bit length of first operand, when address it obviously 64 (on x64 machine). When I use `mov $str, %rdi`, then the left part 32bits are zeroed?

Comment: @PeterCordes despite being address link-time constant, there could be a exception on immediate addresses, since it is clear/obvious the address will always be 64 bit length because of the architecture

Comment: Static addresses fit in 32 bits in the traditional default code model on x86-64 GNU/Linux.  That's why `gcc -fno-pie` code-gen will put addresses in registers with 5-byte `mov $str, %edi`, implicitly zero-extending to 64-bit.  That's also why x86-64 ELF object files have a `32` and `32S` zero/sign-extended relocation type for the linker to fill in absolute addresses as 32-bit values. GCC (compiling C to asm, not assembling hand-written source) will only use RIP-relative with `-fPIE` or `-fPIC`.  My answer on the linked duplicate explains this and more.

Comment: Maybe this question isn't a duplicate after all.  This question is more about why a 32-bit immediate is the default, not just how to do it the normal way.  If you want me to repost that explanation from comments as an answer, I can reopen this and do so.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes I would like to know the background of 32-bit immediate as well (as it could gives me more insight) and since you know a lot about x86, I would like to get an answer from you

Comment: I searched again; I think [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40315803) is a reasonable duplicate; it goes into some detail about when 32-bit immedates work for addresses.  (Which is one reason GAS picks a 32-bit immediate when targeting x86-64 Linux ELF, unless you specify otherwise explicitly.)

Comment: [What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168086) talks about the reasons for code models other than "small" and "small-pic", which would justify using 64-bit absolute addresses sometimes.  e.g. for the "medium" model, only for large arrays; everything else can use normal rel32 or absolute 32-bit addressing.  I also added some more links to the list of duplicates; I think understanding those is your best bet for this to make sense; it won't make sense on its own if you keep thinking that addresses are always 64-bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes from here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy`, I do not undestand the conept `a(%rip) means to calculate a rel32` -> **using a disp32 addressing mode**. Could you give and example in gas syntax (not there)? And what mean disp32? "Displacement by 32 bits?" What does it mean (did get it from that link). In `mov str(%rip),%rdi`, if `%rip` content is `0xffff`, and str absolute address is `0x1234`, then the displacement is `0xffff-0x1234`?

Comment: As we already discussed that just means a 32 bit signed offset added to `%rip`. The displacement is reversed ... it's `symbol - rip` so adding `rip` back gives you the symbol's address. As also said, `rip` already points past the instruction so `rip = address_of_insn + length_of_insn`.

Comment: [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400) explains some about x86-64 addressing modes, and how they can either be a subset of `[base + idx*scale * displacement]` (where displacement is 1 or 4 bytes), or RIP-relative (PC + rel32).  Intel's manuals explain in detail what addressing methods are possible.